# How to access Object ID Identity attribute?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

1. In the IB under Identity tab you can find an attribute called "Object ID". I can not find a way to get hold of this ID from code. Oh, and I know about the tag attribute but it's not what I need.
2. I essentially would like to get the unique object ID for a UIComponent that was touched on the sceen. I already have the UITouch object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Object ID in Interface Builder is only an internal book-keeping value used by IB when deserializing/serializing XIB files, and does no longer exist when the Application runs.

You want to use `tag`, or alternately, a property/outlet.

Comment: I think it still exists at runtime because of Base localization that uses these ids in corresponding strings files.

Comment: @kenji Even if so, using them is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

For UIView I normally use the `tag` property.

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressedid) sender {
NSLog(@"tag: %i", [sender tag]);
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can set the `tag` property in IB :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem with tags is that you have to manualy set them up. I am targeting "object ID" b/c it is automatically assign and unique. Unless there is some other object identity that is assign when the object is created and that does not involve manual setup.

Answer (score 1):

use tags instead of the IB Object ID. As far as I know this object ID is only used in interface builder.

You can set the tag in the Attributes tab.

Comment: Thank you, please look at the comment I gave to willcodejavaforfood.