# Can we get UILabel's name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I was wondering if it is possible to get the name of a `UILabel` (not the text).

Something like this:

```
if([label.name is equalToString:key]){
     //do something
}
```

I know `label.name` doesn't exist but maybe there is something equivalent. How can I do this?

Comment: You could subclass UILabel and add it. You could extend it. Or you could use the tag property which returns an Int.

Comment: Please check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958852/how-to-access-object-id-identity-attribute

Comment: ty !! tag property is perfect

Comment: Could you define your use? Because, if they are all IBOutlet and if it's in a IBAction as sender, or a delegate method, you could use `if (_myLabelOutlet1 == label)`, use tag, or add property with subclassing...

Comment: i need the label's name because i want to [label setText] switch the name of the label.. i will use tag, and then i can use switch/case

Comment: @miDark If you really want to use a name and not just an int value I'd highly recommend looking at the other two methods I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: oh ty ! i will try the answer with swift extension

Comment: @miDark, good idea. It's easy to implement, especially if you already have a bunch of UILabels and don't want to subclass (especially for such a small change to the class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You could subclass UILabel:**

```
// Objective-C

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NMLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end


// Swift
import UIKit

class NMLabel : UILabel {

    var name : String = ""

}
```

**Or at the most basic of levels you can use the already existent `tag` property (in both Objective-C or Swift):**

```
label.tag = 5

// Objective-C

NSLog(@"%d", label.tag); // prints 5

// Swift

print(label.tag) // prints 5
```

Comment: its swift i guess ?

Comment: Yes this is Swift. Not sure if you can use extensions in Objective-C but both subclassing UILabel and tags will work.

Comment: ty !! i use tag, its return int and that's i need

Comment: Awesome, glad I was able to answer this for you. Make sure to select this as the answer.